# Handling callbacks for multiple component instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just starting out with React, trying to replace a functional, though very complex, jQuery page. I'm undertaking this task because there's additional functionality I need to add and to continue using the tangled web of jQuery is going to become untenable.

This page is an order form of sorts, with several destinations and tasks related to the destinations. Everything I've read about React is telling me to hold state at the highest containing level, essentially my OrderCreation/App level - right?

So, now I have a DestinationInput component that handles GoogleAutocomplete through a mixin and has a toggleable edit state (after a autocomplete place is selected, it becomes a pair of h4/h6 nodes - clicking this will swap back to the input field).

I have a few of these DestinationInput components in the same App – I'd prefer not to have 1 destinationUpdated callback per DestinationInput component instance - especially as this will become a dynamic number of instances overtime.

I assume the proper way is to pass down a generic callback method prop to the children and have the children passback an identifier as well as the new value to the parent. Do I use keys? refs? I don't really see any best practices about how to handle multiple child instances updating parent state.

What I'm thinking should work

```
var OrderCreate = React.createClass({
   getIntitialState = function () {
      return {
         destinations: []
      }
   },

   updateDestination = function(id, place) {
      this.setState(destinations[id], place);
   },

   render = function() {
      return (
         for (var i=0; i < this.state.destinations.length; i++) {
            <DestinationInput key={ i }
                              place={this.state.destinations[i]} 
                              onChange={this.updateLocation} />
         };
      );
   }
});

var DestinationInput = React.createClass({
   mixins = [GoogleAutocompleteMixin],
   getIntitialState = function () {
      return {
         text: this.props.text
      };
   },

   getDefaultProps = function() {
      return {
          text: ""
      };
   },

   handleChange = function(event) {
       this.setState({text: event.target.value });
   },

   placeSelected = function(place) {
      this.props.onChange(this.props.key, place);
   },

   render = function() {
      return (
          <input onChange={ this.handleChange } value={ this.state.text } />
      );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flux is a client-side methodology for implementing data stores in memory, as such it is totally agnostic to anything happening on the server.

I'm not sure exactly what you are after but I think you are just asking whether passing functions to children is a good idea. Yes it is, a very good one.

*For brevity I've tried to just include the important function passing stuff.*

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    this.props.onClick( this.props.id )
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={ this.onClick.bind( this ) }>Click me</button>
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  onDoStuff( stuff ) {
    console.log( stuff ) // comes from each button
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button id="number1" onClick={ this.onDoStuff } />
        <Button id="number2" onClick={ this.onDoStuff } />
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

`Parent.onDoStuff` gets passed to the `Button` component, where a handler will eventually be attached to the DOM node which will resolve to calling `onDoStuff` (`this.props.onClick`) and passing back relevant data to the parent component. From there you can decide whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Ok, cool -- kind of what I was thinking (I hope my new example does at least). I was trying to decipher the best way to pass functions to children but know which child was calling the function. So I would make onDoStuff accept(stuff, value) where stuff - by your example is the id of the Button? Looks like I misunderstood Flux, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, as you're passing a function around you can pass whatever you like back as parameters. I'm currently using [single-arity functions](https://gcanti.github.io/2014/09/25/six-reasons-to-define-constructors-with-only-one-argument.html) but you can implement however you like. I'm passing back a prop but you can of course pass back anything, including the raw (synthetic) DOM event if you really wanted to.